# Elliptic curve scalar point multiplication

Tags: elliptic-curves

I need to compute ecc multiplication with this values : $ P=(1,3)\space ; \space k=2 \space ; \space a=24 \space ; \space b= 13 \space ;\space p=29 $ which means $y^{2}=x^{3}+24x+13 \space$. as far as I know in such situation one should compute values using this formula :

$
\lambda= \frac{3x^{2}+a}{2y}
$

$
x_r=\lambda^2 - 2x
$

$
y_r=\lambda(x-x_r) - y
$

when I calculate equation I end up $R=(18.25 , 6.375)$ where true answer of this shoud be $R=(11,10)$ (this site proves it : http://www.christelbach.com/eccalculator.aspx). please help me to find my calculation mistake.

> note : just if you are interested I'm using this matlab code :

```
   temp=(3*(x1^2)+a)/(2*y1);
   x3=mod(temp^2-x1-x2,n);
   y3=mod((x1-x3)*temp-y1,n);
```

Answer (score 3):

For adding, subtracting, and multiplying modulo 29, you can just do the operation in the integers and take it modulo 29 (as you're already doing). To find $a/b$, however, you need to use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find the inverse of $b$ modulo 29, then compute $a \cdot b^{-1}$. [This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14380829/1979005) has pseudocode for the extended Euclidean algorithm. Your **mistake** is trying to use ordinary division to compute `temp`.

Multiply $3x^2 + a$ by the inverse of $2y$ to compute `temp` in your code and you should be good, at least if your goal is to multiply $P$ by 2. If you want to add distinct points, you need to compute $\lambda$ with a different formula, but the rest is the same; if you want to multiply by something other than 2, you should implement something akin to exponentiation by squaring.

Answer (score 1):

The duplication formula for elliptic curves $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$ (over a field $K$ with $char(K)\not=2\ $) is
$$x(2P)=\frac{x^4-2Ax^2-8Bx+A^2}{4y^2}$$
Setting $x=1,y=3$ you get $x(2P)=\frac{19}{36}.$ You have to compute the previous fraction in the finite field $GF(29).$ This is computed as $19\cdot 36^{-1}\pmod {29} = 11.$

Further you can copy-paste the following (sage)-code in [sagecell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)

```
p=29
E=EllipticCurve(GF(p),[0,0,0,24,13])
E;
P=E(1,3)
2*P
```